# Cython doesn't recognize pymalloc Python

Tags: python, cython, distutils, conda-forge

I have a conda environment which exhibits a bug when using Cython. I was not able to reduce the dependency list without making the bug disappear, so here is the full environment:

```
# environment.yml
name: test
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pip
  - compilers
  - make
  - setuptools
  - cython
  - daetk
  - hdf5 =*=*mpich*
  - h5py =*=*mpich*
  - metis
  - mpich
  - numpy
  - openblas
  - parmetis
  - petsc4py
  - petsc
  - python=3
  - scorec
  - superlu
  - superlu_dist
  - triangle
  - pychrono
  - mpi4py
  - gmsh
  - matplotlib
  - mpi4py
  - nose
  - pytables
  - pytest
  - pytest-cov
  - pytest-xdist
  - scipy
  - tetgen
  - ncurses
  - pychrono
  - python=3
  - future
  - ipyparallel
  - pillow
  - recordtype
```

Create the environment with: `conda env create -f environment.yml`

Activate it: `conda activate test`

Create a file `helloworld.pyx`:

```py
print("Hello World")
```

Create a `setup.py`:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

Cythonize it: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

When you import it with `python -c "import helloworld"`, you get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'
```

It created a file `helloworld.cpython-37-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, where it should have been `helloworld.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. Indeed you can verify that it works fine if you rename it:

```
mv helloworld.cpython-37-x86_64-linux-gnu.so helloworld.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

And in the conda environment the `m` suffix is present: `$CONDA_PREFIX/include/python3.7m`. I know it is related with whether Python was compiled with pymalloc, but I don't understand why Cython doesn't see that it was in this case.

Comment: I suspect this is possibly distutils issue (since I think it's distutils that chooses the filename). That doesn't help you fix it though

Comment: Thanks @DavidW, you are right. I can already see the root of the problem, since the following doesn't have the m suffix: python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var; print(get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX'))"

Comment: [This bug report](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11195) looks similar

Comment: That report was for the default channel of conda, but not the conda-forge channel. In my case, the exact same Python version behaves differently in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually caused by a broken build of Python 3.7.6 in conda-forge. It has been fixed.